# Print a pdf using TCPDF in ajax success still blank page

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pdf

I have a problem to print a pdf using TCPDF. The storyboard is, I have a search form, and I displayed the result into a table. My purpose is, The users can print out this table into a PDF in new window of browser like `window.open` in javascript when clicked a button. I use ajax to send some data , in this case, I send the contains of `<tbody></tbody>`. Now, in ajax success, I dont know how I must supposed to do. This is my code.

**HTML**

```
<tbody id="hasil-pencarian">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>TMS/IT/06/001</td>
    <td>Erika Julia Widiyanti</td>
    <td>Marketing</td>
    <td>14-06-2015 13:59</td>
    <td>14-06-2015 14:00</td>
    <td>Erika test 1</td>
    <td>Jawab erika request 1<br></td>
    <td>14-06-2015 15:00</td>
    <td>15-06-2015 17:19</td>
    <td class="center" width="10px">
       <a class="btn btn-success"><i class="halflings-icon white print" id="print"></i>Print</a>
   </td>
  </tr>

<p class="center">
  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="print-bottom">Print Data Di atas</button>
</p>
```

**This is the ajax on jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '#print-bottom', function() {
var result = $("#hasil-pencarian").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'it_team/control_it/generate_pdf' ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {result: result},
            success: function() {
                //it still gives me a blank content of table if I use like this :
                window.open("<?php echo base_url() . 'it_team/control_it/generate_pdf/' ?>", "_blank", "top=25, left=250, toolbar=no, width=1000, height=600"); 
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
    });
 });
```

**And this is the TCPDF**

```
public function generate_pdf() {
    if (($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "logging") && ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "IT")) {
        redirect('control_auth');
    } else {
        $this->load->library("tcpdf");
        //Post from ajax
        $html = $this->input->post('result');

        $pdf = new tcpdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);

        // This is for <th> header
        $tbl = <<<EOD
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
          <tr>
           <td align="center" width='1px'><b> No.  </b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>No_Req</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Nama user</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Dept</b></td>                                            
           <td align="center"><b>Masuk ke IT</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Diterima IT</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Keluhan</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Tindakan IT</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Estimasi</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b>Tutup Request</b></td>
         </tr>

      EOD;

        // Adding the content of table based from post ajax
        $tbl = $tbl. $html;
        $tbl = $tbl . "</table>";
        $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
        $pdf->Output('example_048.pdf', 'I');
    }
}
```

Comment: solve this issue?